# Integral of Lie derivative and the fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, differential-forms, lie-derivative, pullback

Assume $M$ to be a smooth manifold, and denote by $j_t:M\rightarrow[0,1]\times M, x\mapsto (t,x)$ the inclusion of $M$ into $[0,1]\times M$. Let $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ be the canonical vector field on $[0,1]\times M$ with respect to the coordinate $t$ on the interval $[0,1]$. Then show that for any $k$-form $\beta$ on $[0,1]\times M$:
$$
\int_0^1 j_t^*(\mathcal{L}_{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}}\beta)dt = j_1^*\beta - j_0^*\beta \,.
$$
To me this looks a lot like a ''Lie derivative version" of the fundamental theorem of calculus, but I have not found a convincing argument that proves the above equality.

Comment: Write $\beta$ with respect to $t$ and local coordinates on $M$.

Comment: I would argue this is just the ordinary fundamental theorem of calculus, disguised a bit using product manifolds and Lie derivatives. If you write it in terms of a $1$-parameter family of $k$-forms $\beta_t:=j_t^*\beta$, you can rewrite it as $\int_0^1\frac{d}{dt}(\beta_t)\ dt=\beta_1-\beta_0$.